# Crons keeps sending to root

Tags: cron, centos5

My `crontab` keeps sending emails to root user email. 
I have already tried to fix the problem by editing the followings:

In `/etc/crontab` edited the following:

```
MAILTO=root
```

to

```
MAILTO=email@domain.com
```

and restarted service by running `service crond restart`.

But cron results are still sent to root email address and not to the specified email address in crontab.

How can I fix that, any ideas?

Comment: what do the logs (/var/log/cron) say? Perhaps there is a certain cronjob that sends mails to the root user email. The log should indicate what job is sending the email.

Comment: `contab -l`, what does it output? Probably you have crons executing from other configs. Also, you should not need a crond restart.

Comment: I call php file which prints out and output texts which should be mailed to my specified email address, but it does not.

In log file, I can see that php is called...
php -q /path/to/script/cron.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your system can send mail outside? Try with the `mail` command:

```
echo "Hello, world" | mail email@domain.com
```

If you receive an e-mail, then check if the `/etc/aliases` file contains anything that aliases `email@domain.com` to root.

If you don't receive an e-mail, check in the spam folder. If there's nothing there, check your mailer logs in `/var/log/`. There will be an error explaining what is happening.

Comment: I have tried to send mail to email@domain.com and I do receive the mail without problems. I can also send mails from that mail adresse.

no aliases for that mail points to root
It used to work before but all of a sudden stopped and keeps sending to root mail